# Need to replace a specific url path in a Webpage using ChromeExtension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have lot of js/css files in a WebPage and I just need to load them from a localhost instead of the remote server

All of them start with a specific url pattern.

Whether I should use replace javascript function to replace it so that they load from the local instead of from a server or should I modify the WebRequests that is being sent when the page loads up?

Comment: Using javascript the elements making the requests through `src` or `href` have to exist before you can modify them...therefore it's too late to prevent initial requests

Comment: Do you have extensions that do this job:
https://github.com/kudos/punkjs

Comment: Use a MutationObserver (it's executed by browser as a _blocking_ microtask) to substitute the urls. From what I see in devtools->network none of initial image src urls slip though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned, you could listen to [`chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest) event and redirect specific requests via setting the [`filter`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-RequestFilter)

Comment: great @Haibara, but can u help me as well?
I have unresolved case here.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57971048/how-to-call-creating-new-contact-api-after-chromeextension-oauth-succeed